# Using index of multidimensional array to get value of another array

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array, arraylist, indexing

Ok so basically I have 2 multidimensional arrays in my program:

Distances Generated: 
    null

```
999.0   22.0    38.0    9.0     12.0

10.0    999.0   9.0     22.0    24.0

10.0    41.0    999.0   25.0    49.0

4.0     2.0     18.0    999.0   1.0

4.0     38.0    8.0     20.0    999.0
```

Roads Matrix:

```
null     town     town       national   regional
town     null     national   motorway   motorway
town     motorway null       regional   town
motorway national national   null       town
town     town     national   regional   null
```

The first array generates the distances while the second array generates the road types of these distances.

I am using an algorithm to calculate the most optimum route, which I have working on the first matrix. I used an array list.

[0, 4, 3, 1, 2, 0]

and basically I want to get the indexes of the roads in my second array.

The result should be as follows [ regional,regional,national,national,town]

I'm just wondering what is the most efficient way of doing this using the result generated from the first matrix?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you have a single 2-dimensional array of some complex type... Node(distance, road) and have your algorithm that does the calculation read the distance off a Node instead of directly as a value from the array. Likewise, whatever populates the two arrays would just construct a `new Node` in a single pass? Does this not work for you for some reason?

Comment: Please explain the meaning of the list, and how the resulting list is obtained.  Either the examples are inconsistent or it's not trivial to figure out.

Comment: @Doug Thank you this is what I wanted to do in the first place, but finding it hard to implement. I was thinking something along the lines of  creating a new object > Object result = new Object[distance.length, road.length][]. Thank you for your advice and sorry for my lack of understanding I'm just struggling with these 2 matrices and can't seem to grasp them

Comment: @MarioRossi Thank you for reply. I am using a branch and bound algorithm to obtain the results, this is on the first matrix, I have nothing implemented on the 2nd matrix, basically want to get the index of the values in the 2nd matrix from the index's obtained in the first. Sorry for my poor understanding of all this

Comment: @user2302621 You just need to create a new class. Just like the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the data in the first array to fill the second one, the best is to keep them both near each other to prevent as much cache misses as possible.

For instance:

```
public class Road {
  public float distance;
  public RoadType roadType;
};

// if you know the size, try using an actual array of Road
List<Road> roads;
```

Unless you want better efficiency on the access of that data - then you may need to change the memory layout of your data. (in the case above, it should be efficient at creation time)